# How to execute a command on a running docker container?

Tags: hadoop, docker, boot2docker

I have a container running hadoop. I have another docker file which contains Map-Reduce job commands like creating input directory, processing a default example, displaying output. Base image for the second file is hadoop_image created from first docker file.

**EDIT**

Dockerfile - for hadoop

```
 #base image is ubuntu:precise
 #cdh installation
 #hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo installation
 #CMD to start-all.sh
```

start-all.sh

```
 #start all the services under /etc/init.d/hadoop-*
```

hadoop base image created from this.

Dockerfile2

```
 #base image is hadoop
 #flume-ng and flume-ng agent installation
 #conf change
 #flume-start.sh
```

flume-start.sh

```
#start flume services
```

I am running both containers separately. It works fine. But if i run

```
docker run -it flume_service
```

it starts flume and show me a bash prompt [/bin/bash is the last line of flume-start.sh]. The i execute

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

in the second running container, i am getting the following error

ls: Call From 514fa776649a/172.17.5.188 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

I understand i am getting this error because hadoop services are not started yet. But my doubt is my first container is running. I am using this as base image for second container. Then why am i getting this error? Do i need to change anything in hdfs-site.xml file on flume contianer?

Pseudo-Distributed mode installation.

Any suggestions?

Or Do i need to expose any ports and like so? If so, please provide me an example

**EDIT 2**

```
  iptables -t nat -L -n
```

I see

```
  sudo iptables -t nat -L -n
  Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination
  DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           ADDRTYPE match dst-

  Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination
  MASQUERADE  tcp  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24    masq ports: 1024-6
  MASQUERADE  udp  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24    masq ports: 1024-6
  MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24
  MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination
  DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8         ADDRTYPE match dst-

 Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 target     prot opt source               destination
```

It is in docker@domian. Not inside a container.

**EDIT**
   See last comment under surazj' answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried linking the container?

For example, your container named **hadoop** is running in psedo dist mode. You want to bring up another container that contains flume. You could link the container like

```
 docker run -it --link hadoop:hadoop  --name flume ubuntu:14.04 bash
```

when you get inside the flume container - type **env** command to see ip and port exposed by hadoop container.

From the flume container you should be able to do something like. (ports on hadoop container should be exposed)

```
$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs://<hadoop containers IP>:8020/
```

The error you are getting might be related to some hadoop services not running on flume. do **jps** to check services running. But I think if you have hadoop classpath setup correctly on flume container, then you can run the above hdfs command (-ls hdfs://:8020/) without starting anything. But if you want

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

to work on flume container, then you need to start hadoop services on flume container also.

On your core-site.xml add **dfs.namenode.rpc-address** like this so namenode listens to connection from all ip

```
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:8020</value>
  </property>
```

Make sure to restart the namenode and datanode

**sudo /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode restart && sudo /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-datanode restart**

Then you should be able to do this from your hadoop container without connection error, eg

> ```
> hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:8020/
> hadoop fs -ls hdfs://172.17.0.11:8020/
> ```

On the linked container. Type env to see exposed ports by your hadoop container

> env

You should see something like
HADOOP_PORT_8020_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.11:8020

Then you can verify the connection from your linked container.

> telnet 172.17.0.11 8020

Comment: It is fine with this map-reduce example. I am instaling cdh4.6.0. It is running in one container. Now i have flume installation instruction on another docker file. Flume requires hadoop? But it is running as a seperate container. If flume commands are part of same hadoop_first_docker_file, it ll work fine. But if it is a seperate file, it requires commands getting executed on running container. How to execute/specify second_docker_file commands on hadoop_first_docker_file container? Is it clear now? Thanks.

Comment: If your main concern is to just share the script from the container 1, then you can attach a volume to both container and move the script to the volume. so both container has access to the volume (i.e. -v flag). 

On your installing, you are trying to run flume in standalone mode in second container, I don't see the issue. Are you trying to write to hdfs from flume?

Comment: Yes suraj. I am facing issues while trying to access hdfs from second dockerfile. Because services are running on the container started from first docker file

Comment: I want to achieve "Sample flume program running on Docker2 flume container with sink as HDFS from Docker1 hadoop container".

Comment: Thanks Suraj. I don't want to start hadoop services in flume container. Without starting them, i want to do. I have tried **env** but no ports shown up and iptables are also not working. and i tried *hadoop fs -ls hdfs://8020/    hadoop fs -ls hdfs://:8020/*. first says socketexception and later is invalid argument. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi surajz, I re-tried everything. It almost fine. I can see all the env variable formed automatically by docker while linking. But when i try `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://172.17.0.179:8020/` I see connection refused error at port 8020. but i can able to ping the hadoop host. my exposed ports are 50070,80,22,500105 and two more. But not 8020. I tried with 80 instead 8020. Getting the same error. Any idea?

Comment: Hi Gops, In case you have not figured it out. You have 2 options. Use a script to change the fs.defaultFS to point to your ip (172.17.0.179) using some tool like set. Or open up the namenode.rpc-address so namenode will access connection. see the example of second option above.

Answer (score 0):

I think I met the same problem yet. I either can't start hadoop namenode and datanode by hadoop command "start-all.sh" in docker1.

That is because it launch namenode and datanode through "hadoop-daemons.sh" but it failed. The real problem is "ssh" is not work in docker.

So, you can do either

- (solution 1) : 
  Replace all terms "daemons.sh" to "daemon.sh" in start-dfs.sh, 
  than run start-dfs.sh
- (solution 2) :  do

  $HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
  $HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode

You can see datanode and namenode are working fine by command "jps"

Regards.